# Pytest line coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest-cov

I do a unit test with pytest and it work fine, but I am trying to do a line coverage using pytest-cov but it not work because raise a module import error.
Here my file tree:

```
MATCHING_CC/
    - pytest.ini
    - __init__.py               (empty file)
    - conftest.py               (empty file)
    - src/
        - __init__.py           (empty file)
        - conftest.py           (empty file)
        - matching_ingr_zing.py
        - services/
            - __init__.py       (empty file)
            - ElasticSearch.py
            - ingredient_extractor_for_search.py
            - metrics.py
            - stop_word_matching.py
    - models/        (folder to save trained models)
    - tests/
        - __init__.py                (empty file)
        - test_services/
            - __init__.py            (empty file)
            - test_elastic_search.py
            - test_ingredient_extractor_for_search.py
            - test_metrics.py
        - test_src/
            - __init__.py                (empty file)
            - test_matching_ingr_zingr.py
```

files:
pytest.ini

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = -p no:warnings
filterwarnings = ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
```

When I run the test with the command `python -m pytest tests/` from the folder `MATCHING_CC` all the tests are performed well but when I try to run `pytest --cov=MATCHING_CC tests/` from the same folder a module import error is raised.

```
error when using pytest --cov=MATCHING_CC tests/ command:

    ======================================================================================= ERRORS =======================================================================================
    ____________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_services/test_elastic_search.py _____________________________________________________________
    ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\zaply\Desktop\Zaply\Zaply_ML_test_V1\MACHTING_CC\tests\test_services\test_elastic_search.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    ..\..\..\..\miniconda3\envs\match_prod_ingr\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    tests\test_services\test_elastic_search.py:5: in <module>
        from src.services.ElasticSearch import make_client, search_ingredient_normal, search_ingredient_fuzzy, search, complete_synonyms
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
    ____________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_services/test_ingredient_extractor_for_search.py ____________________________________________________
    ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\zaply\Desktop\Zaply\Zaply_ML_test_V1\MACHTING_CC\tests\test_services\test_ingredient_extractor_for_search.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    ..\..\..\..\miniconda3\envs\match_prod_ingr\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    tests\test_services\test_ingredient_extractor_for_search.py:5: in <module>
        from src.services.ingredient_extractor_for_search import convert_to_float, text_normalization
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
    ________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_services/test_metrics.py ________________________________________________________________
    ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\zaply\Desktop\Zaply\Zaply_ML_test_V1\MACHTING_CC\tests\test_services\test_metrics.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    ..\..\..\..\miniconda3\envs\match_prod_ingr\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    tests\test_services\test_metrics.py:6: in <module>
        from src.services.metrics import sorted_levenshtein_rate, levenshtein, metrics_calc
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
    ____________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_src/test_matching_ingr_zingr.py _____________________________________________________________
    ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\zaply\Desktop\Zaply\Zaply_ML_test_V1\MACHTING_CC\tests\test_src\test_matching_ingr_zingr.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    ..\..\..\..\miniconda3\envs\match_prod_ingr\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    tests\test_src\test_matching_ingr_zingr.py:5: in <module>
        from src.matching_ingr_zingr import ingr_zing_match
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
    
    ---------- coverage: platform win32, python 3.7.13-final-0 -----------
    
    ============================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================
    ERROR tests/test_services/test_elastic_search.py
    ERROR tests/test_services/test_ingredient_extractor_for_search.py
    ERROR tests/test_services/test_metrics.py
    ERROR tests/test_src/test_matching_ingr_zingr.py
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 4 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ================================================================================= 4 errors in 0.75s ==================================================================================
```

I have been tried a lot of variations for pytest-cov, but I always fall in the import module problem. I can't understand why `pytest -m` works fine but `pytest --cov` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED: from CLI in the root folder (in my case MATCHING_CC) run the command "overage report -m" and it's done.